# Redux-form not getting installed & npm install not administrator errors

Tags: node.js, npm-install, redux-form

I am trying to install redux-form & redux-form-material-ui using npm install, but its showing you need to install peer dependencies first, which I am doing but these modules are still not available under node modules folder.

I am running 'npm install' in git bash as an administrator but its showing run as a root/administrator. However its running when I am using 'npm install -g', I am not getting the reason for this odd behavior.
However still after using -g those modules are not getting installed - Error of module not found is coming.

**Environment?**

> Node version - 8.0.0 ( Even tried with v6) npm - 5.4.0 Redux form
>   -latest OS- Windows 10

**Logs**-

> $ npm install redux-form npm ERR! path
>   D:\ABC\template\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\aproba\package.json
>   npm ERR! code EPERM npm ERR! errno -4048 npm ERR! syscall unlink npm
>   ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink
>   'D:\ABC\template\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\aproba\package.json'
>   npm ERR! { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink
>   'D:\ABC\template\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\aproba\package.json'
>   npm ERR! stack: 'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink
>   'D:\ABC\template\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\aproba\package.json'',
>   npm ERR! errno: -4048, npm ERR! code: 'EPERM', npm ERR! syscall:
>   'unlink', npm ERR! path:
>   'D:\ABC\template\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\aproba\package.json'
>   } npm ERR! npm ERR! Please try running this command again as
>   root/Administrator. npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found
>   in: npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\dbhowmick.ABC\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2017-09-18T13_03_31_862Z-debug.log

For just 'npm install' same error is coming, even if I am running as administrator.

> $ npm install -g redux-form npm WARN redux-form@7.0.4 requires a peer
>   of react@^15.0.0-0 || ^16.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must
>   install peer dependencies yourself. npm WARN redux-form@7.0.4 requires
>   a peer of react-redux@^4.3.0 || ^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must
>   install peer dependencies yourself. npm WARN redux-form@7.0.4 requires
>   a peer of redux@^3.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer
>   dependencies yourself.
>
> redux-form@7.0.4 added 24 packages in 14.599s Its showing added but no
>   folder created under node modules, & redux form module not found is
>   coming.

For installing redux-form-material-ui same error is coming

$ npm install -g redux-form-material-ui
npm WARN redux-form-material-ui@4.2.0 requires a peer of react@15 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN redux-form-material-ui@4.2.0 requires a peer of redux-form@6 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

redux-form-material-ui@4.2.0
added 1 package in 1.509s

Comment: Even I have created a new directory checked out the code there & tried doing a npm install after deleting the node modules, still nothing helped the cause. When I am doing a just 'npm install' after opening git bash as administrator. This error is still showing, I have closed all processes that are using package.json.

Answer (score 0):

Updating the npm through command prompt(run as administrator) and then installing redux worked for me.

Update:

> npm i -g npm

Install:

> npm install redux --save

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue then I run cmd as administrator 
and run `yarn add react-redux` and it worked for me smoothly.
I think `yarn` is best to use instead of `npm`